Modify Text Colum while Preserving Its Format
I am trying to modify cells of a text column. In particular, I want to be able to remove a part of the text (XXX_) and strikethrough the part that succeeds it (YYYY). Moreover, I also want to preserve whatever format that other text in the cell might have.
Sample data
col1
"lorem ipso, XXX_YYYY, lorem ipso"

What I want is
col1
"lorem ipso, YYYY, lorem ipso"

BUT here's the catch:

the lorem ipso could have arbitrary formatting (different size, color, bold, etc...): I want to be able to preserve its format - this is really crucial.
I want to apply strikethrough to YYYY

I've tried this, but the main issue - and what I haven't figured out - is preserving the format of part of the text; the part that precedes XXX.
Here's what I've tried
Sub ModifyTextSingle()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim txt As String
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    Dim lengthYYYY As Integer
    Dim prefix As String
    
    ' Define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Get last row of data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in column A
    For rowNumber = 1 To lastRow
        Set cell = ws.Cells(rowNumber, 1) ' Adjust the column if needed
        
        ' Get the text from the cell
        txt = cell.Value
        
        ' Find the position of "XXX_"
        position = InStr(txt, "XXX_")
        lengthYYYY = Len("YYYY") ' Length of "YYYY"

        If position > 0 Then
            ' Store any text before "XXX_" ( BUT doesn't save the format)
            prefix = Left(txt, position - 1)
            
            ' Remove "XXX_" but keep the rest (and prepend any text before "XXX_")
            cell.Value = prefix & Mid(txt, position + Len("XXX_"))
            
            ' Find the new position of "YYYY" after "XXX_" is removed
            position = InStr(cell.Value, "YYYY")
            
            If position > 0 Then
                ' Apply strikethrough only to "YYYY"
                cell.Characters(position, lengthYYYY).Font.Strikethrough = True
            End If
        End If
    Next rowNumber
End Sub

Help would be immensely appreciated.

It looks like that the original formatting of the characters gets lost when you change part of it. So the only way would be to first store the formatting per each character (bold, italic, size, strikethrough etc) and then reapply it afterwards ...

I think it doesn't have to be that complicated. The Characters.Delete method will perform this task.
Sub ModifyTextSingle()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim txt As String
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    Dim lengthYYYY As Integer
    
    ' Define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  '"Sheet1"
    
    ' Get last row of data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in column A
    For rowNumber = 1 To lastRow
        Set cell = ws.Cells(rowNumber, 1) ' Adjust the column if needed
        
        ' Get the text from the cell
        txt = cell.Value
        
        ' Find the position of "XXX_"
        position = InStr(txt, "XXX_")
        lengthYYYY = Len("YYYY") ' Length of "YYYY"

        If position > 0 Then
           ' Remove "XXX_" but keep the rest (and prepend any text before "XXX_")
            cell.Characters(position, Len("XXX_")).Delete
            
            ' Find the new position of "YYYY" after "XXX_" is removed
            position = InStr(cell.Value, "YYYY")
            
            If position > 0 Then
                ' Apply strikethrough only to "YYYY"
                cell.Characters(position, lengthYYYY).Font.Strikethrough = True
            End If
        End If
    Next rowNumber
End Sub

Column A = After, Column F = Before


I haven't done too much testing on this, but seems to work - providing the XXXX_ part and YYYY parts are unique within the string.
Before:

After:

Create a class module to store each character format.  I called it cCharFormatting and I haven't added all properties - just enough to show the idea.
Option Explicit

Private Type ClassVar
    Name As String
    FontStyle As String
    Colour As Long
    Size As Long
    StrikeThrough As Boolean
    Superscript As Boolean
    Subscript As Boolean
    OutlineFont As Boolean
    Shadow As Boolean
    Underline As Long
End Type
Private This As ClassVar

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = This.Name
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    This.Name = Value
End Property

Public Property Get FontStyle() As String
    FontStyle = This.FontStyle
End Property
Public Property Let FontStyle(Value As String)
    This.FontStyle = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Colour() As Long
    Colour = This.Colour
End Property
Public Property Let Colour(Value As Long)
    This.Colour = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Size() As Long
    Size = This.Size
End Property
Public Property Let Size(Value As Long)
    This.Size = Value
End Property

Public Property Get StrikeThrough() As Boolean
    StrikeThrough = This.StrikeThrough
End Property
Public Property Let StrikeThrough(Value As Boolean)
    This.StrikeThrough = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Underline() As Long
    Underline = This.Underline
End Property
Public Property Let Underline(Value As Long)
    This.Underline = Value
End Property  

Then add a procedure to record the formatting of each character, update the value of the cell and re-apply the formatting of each character:
Public Sub UpdateValue(Target As Range, Remove As String, StrikeThrough As String)

    'Figure out where the Remove part is.
    Dim RemoveStart As Long
    RemoveStart = InStr(Target.Value, Remove)
    
    Dim RemoveLength As Long
    RemoveLength = Len(Remove)

    'Record the details of each character in the Target value.
    'The 'Remove' part of the string is ignored.
    Dim ClassCollection As Collection
    Set ClassCollection = New Collection

    Dim Ch As String
    Dim Char As cCharFormatting
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    For x = 1 To Len(Target.Value)
        If x >= RemoveStart And x <= RemoveStart + RemoveLength - 1 Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            y = y + 1
            Set Char = New cCharFormatting
            With Target.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font
                Char.Name = .Name
                Char.FontStyle = .FontStyle
                Char.Colour = .Color
                Char.Size = .Size
                Char.StrikeThrough = .StrikeThrough
                Char.Underline = .Underline
            End With
            ClassCollection.Add Char, CStr(y)
        End If
    Next x
    
    'Remove the 'Remove' part of the string.
    Dim NewString As String
    NewString = Replace(Target.Value, Remove, "")
    
    'Figure out where the StrikeThrough part is.
    Dim StrikeThroughStart As Long
    StrikeThroughStart = InStr(NewString, StrikeThrough)
    
    Dim StrikeThroughLength As Long
    StrikeThroughLength = Len(StrikeThrough)
    
    'Update the value in Target and then re-apply the formatting to each character.
    Target = NewString
    For x = 1 To Len(NewString)
        With Target.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font
            .Name = ClassCollection(x).Name
            .FontStyle = ClassCollection(x).FontStyle
            .Color = ClassCollection(x).Colour
            .Size = ClassCollection(x).Size
            If x >= StrikeThroughStart And x <= StrikeThroughStart + StrikeThroughLength - 1 Then
                .StrikeThrough = True
            Else
                .StrikeThrough = ClassCollection(x).StrikeThrough
            End If
            .Underline = ClassCollection(x).Underline
        End With
    Next x

End Sub

You can then call the procedure using:
Public Sub Test()

    UpdateValue ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2"), "xxxx_", "yyyy"

End Sub

